# NVMe SSD is not detected by the Ubuntu 20.04 installer

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, dell, ssd, nvme

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my new Dell 5400 laptop, but the Samsung NVMe SSD ( PM981A ) is not detected by the Ubuntu installer. The laptop allows only the UEFI installation media. I tried many things, but it's still the same. Is there a driver I can get to enable the Ubuntu installation?

Comment: thanks for the advise i revised the bios options and solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

the issue was related to Bios settings , SATA MODE was set to Raid  while it should be AHCI , also i had to close the secure boot to enable the installation

Comment: Answer solved the same issue for a new XPS 8940 for me.